# Mavensmate - compile files retrieved from source control

Tags: mavensmate

I've retrieved some new components from git, however, when compiling these new files, Mavensmate just get stuck in limbo.

This is probably due to fact it is missing from org (or potentially has missing dependancies). What is the correct procedure to push those?

Screenshot: ACRSQueue is existing class, where as others below are new ones.
[image: Fail]

Answer (score 1):

The other classes are not compiled because Mavensmate retrieves your organization's metadata information when you type in your credentials for the project. Since you retrieved them from source control, and they weren't created in your organization, the metadata simply does not exist, and thus Mavensmate does not know where to push the class code. It is something in the line of "hey I don't have the Id for this class, so I don't know where to send its body to."

You probably can fix this by creating empty classes with those names in your organization, and then refreshing the Metadata index in the Mavensmate app, and finally try to do the save.

Comment: Yeah the solution you mention is obvious, but not scalable - I do not really know what I am going to get from source control, I can't account for every possible scenario and then spend fairly large amount of time recreating them manually.

Comment: Well, I'm honestly out of options here. You could write a script to retrieve the metadata from the organization and compare with the files in the folder, but my guess is that this is just a little better, but at the same time really annoying and might cause some headache. Yup, working with Salesforce and version control is just that: a headache.

Comment: Generally yes, more source control stuff should be built into Salesforce. But in this case I think MM is lacking this nearly basic functionality. It's not the first time I am getting disappointed of it. The project seems stale and maintainer is somewhat rude :(

Comment: I've done exactly what @RenatoOliveira suggests, but it's a pain in the $$$. Haven't figured out another solution other than to refresh an entire folder in MM, but sometimes that's just not an option.